# Headless JavaScript Testing HTML5 audio/ video

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, phantomjs, qunit, headless

I know that there is a lot of other similar questions, however the answers don't provide a way round this problem.

I have a JavaScript file used on my website that uses the HTML 5 Web Audio and want to unit test it.

I have looked at using QUnit with PhantomJS and before you say anything I **know** that Phantom doesn't support it (http://phantomjs.org/supported-web-standards.html) however I want to know if there is a way around this?

Testing it using QUnit in the browser works as you would expect but I don't want to have to test it using the browser every time, I want it to be automated on the server.

An example of one of the tests that fails:

```
QUnit.test("isPlaying", function(assert){

    // true case
    My.Sound.play("background");
    assert.ok(My.Sound.isPlaying("background"), "The background audio is playing");

    // false case
    My.Sound.pause("background");
    assert.ok(!My.Sound.isPlaying("background"), "The background audio is not playing");
});
```

Comment: I don't know if QUnit runs with SlimerJS, but if it does you may be able to do this with SlimerJS+xvfb

Comment: You can always mock out the entire Web Audio API... but seems like overkill. What you're testing here is the HTML5 Web Audio works, not your own code.

Comment: Related for automated testing with SlimerJS and xvfb:  https://askubuntu.com/questions/430247/which-packages-should-be-installed-on-ubuntu-server-so-it-will-be-able-to-play-v/430251#430251

Answer (score 0):

As @jakerella already pointed out, it makes no sense to test third party apis. Just focus on your functionality. In this case, you should test that whenever you want to play / pause a sound, you invoke the correct api methods for your sound object (play / pause), which should be stubs of the original implementations.

```
QUnit.test("play button should play sound when clicked", (assert) => {
    const button =  someButton; //...get your button / play trigger here
    const playStub = stub(My.Sound, 'play');

    //trigger button click

    assert.ok(playStub.called);
});
```

Take a look [here](https://github.com/cjohansen/sinon-qunit) for stubbing functionality with QUnit.